# Normalized hit times of a simple RW converge in distribution to hit times of standard Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk

I would appreciate some hints or guidance towards solving the following exercise:

> Let $\left\{ S\left(j\right)\thinspace:\thinspace j=0,1,\ldots\right\}$ 
>     be a simple random walk on the integers started at $S\left(0\right)=0$.
>     Show that as $n\uparrow\infty$
>    :$$\frac{1}{n^{2}}\min\left\{ j\thinspace:\thinspace\left|S\left(j\right)\right|=n\right\} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow}\min\left\{ t\geq0\thinspace:\thinspace\left|B\left(t\right)\right|=1\right\}$$ 
>     where $\left\{ B\left(t\right)\thinspace:\thinspace t\geq0\right\}$
>    is a $1$-dimensional Brownian motion.

Basically I have no good ideas on where to start so I would really appreciate some solid pointers or even better yet a guide towards a solution. I'm willing to offer a bounty should that help.

Comment: Here is an outline that might help: 
1-) Find the moment generating function of the hitting time of BM. It is something like $\frac{1}{\cosh{\sqrt{2\lambda}}}$. 
2-) Find the moment generating functions of the hitting times of your random walks.
3-) Since the MGF in the first step is continuous everywhere, the weak convergence statement in your question is implied.

Comment: Hi Calculon, thanks for your reply. I thought about going in this direction but my problem is that I don't know what the pmf/pdf of the discrete/continuous hitting times are and without those I have no idea how to find the MGF.

Comment: The mgf of the hitting time for BM is easy to derive using martingale techniques. You don't need to find its pdf first. The mgf of the hitting time for RW should also be doable. If I can find time, I will post something later on if nobody else does.

Comment: Indeed the MGF of the hitting time of the simple RW is direct using the Markov property after **one** step. (Rather than some bounty I would much prefer to see you applying these hints. Just my two cents.)

Comment: I have to admit that I simply never saw how to use this sort of technique in order to find moment generating functions. So even though the hints are solid I just don't know how to implement them.

Comment: Look at the process $X_t = \cosh{(\alpha B_t)}e^{-\alpha^2\frac{t}{2}}$. Convince yourself that $X$ is a martingale. (Either by directly using the definition of a martingale or by using Ito's lemma). Then show that $E[X_\tau] = 1$ where $\tau$ is your hitting time for BM. You will need optional stopping and the dominated convergence theorem for this result. Do you see now what the mgf should be?

Comment: @Calculon, I'm afraid that despite your kind attempts I simply don't know how to utilize them. If you're up to writing a detailed solution that would be extremely appreciated. If it's too much of a hassle I understand and thank you regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will follow the outline that I described in my first comment. Let's start with random walk. Fix $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$ and consider the process $(M_j)$ defined as
$$M_j = (\cosh{\alpha})^{-j}\cosh{(\alpha S_j)}$$
We want to show that $(M_j)$ is a martingale with respect to the natural filtration $(\mathcal{F}_j)$ generated by the constituent random variables in $S$. By that I mean $\mathcal{F_j} = \sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_j)$ and $S_j = X_1 + \cdots + X_j$. I took the liberty of assuming that $P\{X_i = 1\} = P\{X_i = -1\} = \frac{1}{2}$ and defined $S_0 = 0$. Of course $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ is an IID sequence.
\begin{align}E[M_j\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}] =& (\cosh{\alpha})^{-j}E[\cosh{(\alpha S_j)}\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}]\\
=& \frac{1}{2}(\cosh{\alpha})^{-j}E[\exp{(\alpha S_j)}+\exp{(-\alpha S_j)}\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}]\\
=&\frac{1}{2}(\cosh{\alpha})^{-j}E[\exp{(\alpha S_{j-1} + \alpha X_j)}+\exp{(-\alpha S_{j-1} -\alpha X_j)}\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}]\\
=&\frac{1}{2}(\cosh{\alpha})^{-j}\left(\exp{(\alpha S_{j-1})} E[\exp{(\alpha X_j)}]+\exp{(-\alpha S_{j-1})} E[\exp{(-\alpha X_j)}]\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{2}(\cosh{\alpha})^{-j}\left(\exp{(\alpha S_{j-1})}\cosh{\alpha}+\exp{(-\alpha S_{j-1})}\cosh{\alpha}\right)\\
=&(\cosh{\alpha})^{-(j-1)}\cosh{(\alpha S_{j-1})} =: M_{j-1}  \end{align}

We want to stop this process at the hitting time $\tau_n:=\inf{\{j: \lvert S_j\rvert = n\}}$, which is a stopping time. Furthermore, it is almost surely finite for each $n$. I will not prove these facts here. Fix $n$. Doob's optional stopping theorem gives
$$E[M_{\tau_n\wedge j}] = E[M_0] = 1$$
Since $\tau_n$ is a.s. finite, $M_{\tau_n\wedge j} \rightarrow M_{\tau_n}$ a.s.
Furthermore, $M_{\tau_n\wedge j} \leq \cosh{(\alpha n)}$. Since $E[\cosh{(\alpha n)}] < \infty$, the dominated convergence theorem can be applied to obtain 
$$E[M_{\tau_n}] = 1$$
Since $\tau_n$ is a.s. finite $\lvert S_{\tau_n}\rvert = n$. This implies $M_{\tau_n} = (\cosh{\alpha})^{-\tau_n}\cosh{(\alpha S_{\tau_n})} = (\cosh{\alpha})^{-\tau_n}\cosh{(\alpha n)}$ because the hyperbolic cosine is an even function. Hence
$$E\left[\left(\frac{1}{\cosh{\alpha}}\right)^{\tau_n}\right] = \frac{1}{\cosh{(\alpha n)}}$$
Now define $\lambda \geq 0$ such that $\exp{(-\frac{\lambda}{n^2})} = \frac{1}{\cosh{\alpha}}$. Then we get
$$E[e^{-\lambda\frac{\tau_n}{n^2}}] = \frac{1}{\cosh{(n\cosh^{-1}{(e^{\frac{\lambda}{n^2}})})}}$$

For the inverse hyperbolic cosine it doesn't matter which value you take (positive or negative) since it is inside another hyperbolic cosine function. So we have found the moment generating function of $\frac{\tau_n}{n^2}$. I will cheat here a bit and use an online tool to compute the limit of $\frac{1}{\cosh{(n\cosh^{-1}{(e^{\frac{\lambda}{n^2}})})}}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The answer is
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh{(n\cosh^{-1}{(e^{\frac{\lambda}{n^2}})})}} = \frac{1}{\cosh{(\sqrt{2\lambda})}}$$

So next we look at the hitting time for Brownian motion. The procedure is **exactly** the same. Start with the process $X_t = \cosh{(\alpha B_t)}\exp{(-\alpha^2\frac{t}{2})}$ and go through the exact same steps as above. For the hitting time $\sigma := \inf{\{t\geq 0: \lvert B_t \rvert = 1 \}}$ we have
$$E[e^{-\lambda\sigma}] = \frac{1}{\cosh{(\sqrt{2\lambda})}}$$

So the moment generating function for scaled hitting time of random walk converges to the moment generating function for hitting time of Brownian motion. Since the latter is continuous everywhere, convergence in distribution follows. This completes the proof.

P.S.
For the computation of the limit I made use of the following:

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+1%2Fcosh%28n*sqrt%28lambda%29*arccosh%28exp%281%2Fn^2%29%29%29+as+n-%3Einfinity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+1%2Fcosh%28n*sqrt%28lambda%29*arccosh%28exp%281%2Fn%5E2%29%29%29+as+n-%3Einfinity)

P.P.S
Here is a computation of the limit. It is enough to show
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\cosh^{-1}{(\exp{(\frac{\lambda}{x^2})})} = \sqrt{2\lambda}$$

First substitute $u = \frac{\lambda}{x^2}$. Then, the above limit is equal to

$$\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{u}}\cosh^{-1}{(e^u)}$$
L'Hopital's rule applies here. Differentiating both the numerator and the denominator with respect to $u$ (and doing some algebraic manipulations) we get
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{u}}\cosh^{-1}{(e^u)} = 2\sqrt{\lambda}\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{u + \frac{u}{e^{2u}-1}} = 2\sqrt{\lambda}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2\lambda}$$

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the detailed solution.
I do have one question, assuming one does not know what result to expect as the MGF of the process. How does one know to look at the process defined as $M_{j}$? 
It seems kind of like magic and I don't have any intuition as to why one would resolve to look at that specific process.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it helped. Regarding how to come up with that process.. I did some playing around myself. I started with $\cosh{(\alpha S_j)}$ because its value at the hitting time is deterministic and it has exponential terms, which are just what you need to arrive at a moment generating function. Then I saw that I had to include the term $(\cosh{\alpha})^{-j}$ to make it a martingale (by the same steps where I show that $M$ IS a martingale.) But the recipe for such problems typically includes finding a **martingale** that contains the terms you are interested in.

Comment: What do you learn from $cosh(\alpha S_{j})$ having deterministic value at the stopping time?
Also there is one equality I don't quite understand, $E[(\frac{1}{\cosh\alpha})^{\tau_{n}}]=\frac{1}{\cosh(\alpha n)}$
Other than that, it is really a very deductive solution and I learnt quite a lot. Thank you again!

Comment: @Serpahimz For an answer to your second question, see my edit. As for your first question, since $\cosh{(\alpha S_j)}$ has a deterministic value at $j = \tau_n$ the randomness in $M_{\tau_n}$ is reduced to the randomness coming from $\tau_n$. This is what allows us to compute its moment generating function.

Comment: Superb, this has been most informative :)